# How to resolve SmartFoxServer connection error in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, smartfoxserver

I'm using SmartFoxServer API on Unity3d. It was working fine before I recovered my MacBook, but now gives a connection error as below:

```
Http error creating http connection: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean requireSocketPolicy) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect (System.Net.IPEndPoint remote_end_point) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect (System.Net.IPAddress[] ipAddresses, Int32 port) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
SFS2X_Connect:OnConnection(BaseEvent) (at Assets/SFS2X_Connect.cs:2758)
Sfs2X.Core.EventDispatcher:DispatchEvent(BaseEvent)
Sfs2X.SmartFox:ProcessEvents()
SFS2X_Connect:Update() (at Assets/SFS2X_Connect.cs:2764)
```

Here is the connection code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using Sfs2X;
using Sfs2X.Core;

    public class SFS2X_Connect : MonoBehaviour {

        public string Host = "127.0.0.1";

        [Tooltip("TCP port listened by the SmartFoxServer 2X instance; used for regular socket connection in all builds except WebGL")]
        public int TcpPort = 9933;

        [Tooltip("WebSocket port listened by the SmartFoxServer 2X instance; used for in WebGL build only")]
        public int WSPort = 8888;

        [Tooltip("Name of the SmartFoxServer 2X Zone to join")]
        public string Zone = "examplezone";


    SmartFox sfs;

          sfs = new SmartFox ();

          sfs.ThreadSafeMode = false;

         sfs.AddEventListener (SFSEvent.CONNECTION, OnConnection);

        ConfigData cfg = new ConfigData();

        cfg.Host = Host;
        cfg.Port = TcpPort;
        cfg.Zone = Zone;

        sfs.Connect (cfg);
    }
```

I've removed and re-imported `smartfox.dll` but still encounter the same error.

What can I do?

Note: I create a new project and imported SnartFoxServer. It's connected to the server.

Comment: Normally Socket Connection get refused if no services listening on the specified port, or there is a firewall stopping you. Have you checked them?

Comment: @Smartis I added more details to question

Comment: Have you already configured the server with http://localhost:8080 ? Whats the message if you type `./sfs2x-service status` in your terminal?

Comment: "the deamon is running"

Comment: And `netstat -p tcp | grep $PORT` in terminal lists 9933 too? Also please add the constructor of `sfs` to your question.

Comment: It gives a plenty of rows of results as a list of IP addresses to paste here. What exactly should I seek for? I edited question

Comment: Look for `127.0.0.1` with TCP `9933` :D

Comment: Did you read that note "Note : I create a new project and import smartfoxserver, its connected to server" No problem at 127.0.0.1 or 9933

Comment: If you create a new project and still work fine with 9933 TCP port, so I think your project has something is missing or corrupted. I think you should check for proxy setting (in your issue project) or compare lib files with working version. Delete/re-copy lib files for luck.

Comment: Do you have to reinstall / refresh Unity3D installation, if you did a separate install ?

Comment: I'd most definitely check if there is an allow rule for port 9933 inbound and outbound on your firewall. (Check router port forwarding if trying to access from outside of localhost). Also do an ipconfig dns flush to be safe? Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

is the zone name really exists and `forceBlueBoxOverHttps` make `true` because apple doesn't accept HTTP connections.

```
cfg.forceBlueBoxOverHttps = true;
```